# Consulta em duas tabelas ao mesmo tempo

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho por exemplo o seguinte cenário:

**Tabela**
        
        
            **Coluna01**
        
        
            **Coluna02**
        
        
            **Coluna03**
        
    
     
        
            livro
        
        
                 id
        
        
                          nome
        
        
                   genero
        
    

        
            captl
        
        
                id
        
        
                          nome
        
        
                   conteudo
        
    


        
            cplivro
        
        
            id
        
        
                          idcap
        
        
                    idlivro

Quando tenho que associar um livro a um capítulo uso a tabela `cplivro` colocando o `id` do livro e o `id` do capítulo.

Quando por exemplo tenho o livro com `id 1` e quero achar os capitúlos dele faço 'dois' `SELECT`:

- Primeiro buscando todos registros em `cplivro` onde o `idlivro` é
  igual a 1.
- Segundo em um for buscando na tabela captl um elemento do    `array`
  resultante do primeiro `SELECT`

É vantajoso fazer assim? Tentei pesquisar um pouco e acho que o `UNION` serviria para isso, mas não consegui entender, como seria com o `UNION`?

Comment: O que você quer na verdade é fazer um `JOIN`. Eu acho que a sua query ficaria  mais ou menos assim: `SELECT 
    livro.*, cplivro.*, captl.*
FROM
    livro
        INNER JOIN
    cplivro ON (cplivro.idlivro = livro.id AND cplivro.idcap = captl.id);`

Comment: Também, me parece desnecessário a existência da tabela `cplivro`. Eu moveria o campo `cplivro.idlivro` para a tabela `captl`.

Comment: Cara o melhor é o `JOIN`, você pode unir as duas tabelas pelas chaves comuns, no caso o id do livro

Answer (score 1):

Vantajoso não é, mas também não é tão ruim. O melhor mesmo seria você tem sua tabela `Livro`com todos os detalhes do livro, se você vai detalhar os capítulos do livro em uma outra tabela então você vai ter um relacionamento 1 para N, nisso é melhor você ter o `id` do livro na tabela `detalhe`, ou seja sua tabela `Capitulos`, dessa forma se você precisa dos detalhes do livro e já sabe qual é o livro você só precisaria buscar os detalhes pelo `Id` do livro.

Mas se você não puder alterar a sua tabela você pode esta fazendo o uso `JOIN`

```
Select * from cplivro L
join captl c
on c.idCapt = l.idCapt
where l.idlivro = 1;
```

Só um detalhe que você falar, seu primeiro select retorna um array, se é isso então na tabela Livro você tem os `Ids` de todos os capítulos, etão se você que um capitulo especifico basta filtra.

```
Select * from cplivro L
join captl c
on c.idCapt = l.idCapt
where l.idlivro = 1
and c.idCapt =1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Como o felipsmartins disse:

> Também, me parece desnecessário a existência da tabela cplivro. Eu moveria o campo cplivro.idlivro para a tabela captl. – felipsmartins

Ao meu ver a relação Livro-Capítulo é uma relação 1 para N, logo a terceira tabela (`cplivro`) realmente não é necessária. Ela seria apenas se a relação fosse muitos para muitos, mas não acho que seja o caso. Afinal um capítulo pertence a um livro somente, o mesmo capítulo não está presente em mais de um livro.

Sendo assim a sua estrutura de tabelas ficaria assim:

**Tabela**
        
        
            **Coluna01**
        
        
            **Coluna02**
        
        
            **Coluna03**
        
        
            **Coluna04**
        
    
     
        
            livro
        
        
                 id
        
        
                          nome
        
        
                   genero
        
        
                   
        
    

        
            captl
        
        
                id
        
        
                          nome
        
        
                   conteudo
        
        
              id_livro

Por fim, para saber os capítulos com suas informações do livro 1, bastaria fazer:

```
SELECT * FROM captlt WHERE id_livro = 1;
```